# Adjust where HTML gets rendered in a map loop

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of HTML elements that I want to render on a page, but depending on the element I'd like to adjust how they get wrapped.

```
const sections = [
  {
    id: 'top',
  },
  {
    id: 'left',
  },
  {
    id: 'right',
  },
  {
    id: 'bottom',
  }
]

const Element = (props) => {
  return <div id={props.id}>hello</div>
}

const ArticleRightRail = (props) =>
  <div>
    <header>
    </header>
    <article>
      {sections.map((section, i) => <Element key={i} {...section} >hello!</Element> )}
    </article>
  </div>
```

In the example above I want any `id` which is not `top` or `bottom` to be rendered within `<article>`, and anything that is `top` or `bottom` to be rendered within `<header>` tags. What is the best way of handling a situation like this with React?

Answer (score 0):

Use ES6 array filter method to filter **sections** array as below:

```
const listForHeader = sections.filter((section, i) => {
    return section === "top" || section === "bottom";
});

const listForArticle = sections.filter((section, i) => {
    return section != "top" || section != "bottom";
})
```

Then use above 2 lists in HEADER and ARTICLE tags respectively using array **map** method.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. I'm not sure how to use what you're proposing.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
const listHeader = sections.filter((section, i) => {
return section === "top" || section === "bottom";
 });

const listArticle = sections.filter((section, i) => {
return section != "top" || section != "bottom";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@JamesIves, the react code is:

```
const listForHeader = sections.filter((section, i) => {
    return section === "top" || section === "bottom";
});

const listForArticle = sections.filter((section, i) => {
    return section != "top" || section != "bottom";
})

const ArticleRightRail = (props) =>
  <div>
    <header>
      {listForHeader.map((section, i) => <Element key={i} {...section} >hello!</Element> )}
    </header>
    <article>
      {listForArticle.map((section, i) => <Element key={i} {...section} >hello!</Element> )}
    </article>
  </div>
```